# chappg prevents glossary from printing

Tags: packages, page-numbering, glossaries

I am writing a report with several chapters. I have the page numbering by chapter using the chappg package and `\pagenumbering{bychapter}`. In the beginning of the document I want to have a glossary. The problem is that the glossary doesn't show up in the document as soon as I turn on the chappg page numbering by chapter. I have searched for chappg in the glossaries documentation and vice versa without any hits.

I'm compiling with pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Minimum code example. The glossary works, but not the page number by chapter. If I switch the commented line, the opposite works.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[auto]{chappg}       % For chapter separated page numbering
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section]{glossaries}      

\newglossaryentry{glsentry1}{
    name=Glossary Entry One,
    description={Description of glossary entry}
}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

% \pagenumbering{arabic}            % Glossary doesn't show without this line
\pagenumbering{bychapter}       % Glossary doesn't show with this line

\printglossary[style=list,title=Glossary]
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{First}
Chapter text for chapter 1. \gls{glsentry1}

\chapter{Second}
More text.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to have both a glossary and page numbering by chapter?

main.glg reports the error like this:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./main.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file main.glo...
!! Input index error (file = main.glo, line = 1):
   -- Illegal Arabic digit: position 2 in 1-1.
done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in main.gls.
Transcript written in main.glg.
```

Comment: Try to put `\printglossary`directly after the`\tableofcontents` call and you should see your glossary as well as a chapterwise numbering (at least that's the case for me). Or did i miss something here? Because you put `nonumberlist` in the package call and so there isn't any page info in the glossary itself.

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't solve it for me. It works if I compile (pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex(x2)) without `\pagenumbering{bychapter}` and then once with `\pagenumbering{bychapter}` using latexmk compiler. But it gives this warning and doesnet work on the second compile. 
"Hyper target `1.1' can't be formed by prefixing
location `1-1'. You need to modify the definition of \theHpage
otherwise you will get the warning: "`name{page.1-1}' has been
 referenced but does not exist" on input line 33."